# Find all entire functions with real part greater than 1 and imaginary part less than -1

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I'm stuck on the following question:

> Find all entire functions $f$ such that $Re(f) >1$ and $Im(f)<-1$.

Unfortunately this doesn't seem like a problem that can be quickly solved by liouville's theorem, so the next idea I had was to use the power series expansion of $f$ and try to figure out something with that, but I'm not sure how to proceed since using the power series is a little messy to do if you have to consider the real and imaginary parts separately.

source: [Spring 1992](https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/990/docs/Pre_2012_papers/complex_analysis_Pre_2011.pdf)

Comment: Are you familiar with Picard's Little Theorem?

Comment: The function $\frac 1{f(x)}$ is entire and bounded.

Comment: You can map the region $\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\ \frac{z+\overline{z}}{2}>1,\ \frac{z-\overline{z}}{2i}<-1\right\}$ to the unit disc. Then apply Liouville.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that$$\left|e^{-f(z)}\right|=e^{-\operatorname{Re}f(z)}<e^{-1}.$$Therefore, $e^{-f}$ is bounded and so…